# Android Java Vertex Array?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, vertex

When I used to program for the iphone I used structs to store my vertices using a nested for loop for tiling.
Now in java I cannot seem to find a way to do this.
Can anyone help me out on this one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a struct in Java. You could of course create your own `Vertex` class (with two values for the X and Y coordinate), but I quesss the easiest thing would be to just use the build-in [Point](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a [`Buffer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/Buffer.html) with a few helper methods for packing data the way you want.